# Haskell let ..... in let ..... in let

Tags: haskell, let

got some code to complete. But I don't know how to  handle the nasted let in expression. Thats the code:

```
data Zutat = Tomate | Fleisch | Salat
data Bun = Weizen | Roggen
data Sosse = Ketchup Sosse | Mayo Sosse | Keine
data Burger = Burger Bun [Zutat] Sosse
```

and I need to complete the code:

```
let zt =               in -- Zutat
  let so =               in -- Sosse
    let dw =
```

`dw` has to be like `dw = Weizen [Tomate,Fleisch,Fleisch] (Mayo (Ketchup Keine))`

got this:

```
zt = [Tomate,Fleisch,Fleisch]
so = Mayo (Ketchup Keine)
dw = Burger Weizen zt so
```

but how can I build it into the let in expression?

Comment: Do I see a homework question copied verbatim?

Comment: Homework or not (well, it _evidently_ is homework, but anyway...), it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I also don't see why you want to construct this with `let` expressions anyway. What is wrong with `dw = Weizen [Tomate,Fleisch,Fleisch] (Mayo (Ketchup Keine))` in the first place? There are no duplicates in the construction, so you cannot save on memory either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just insert those expressions into the `let` expressions:

```
let zt = [Tomate, Fleisch, Fleisch] in
  let so = Mayo (Ketchup Keine) in
    let dw = Burger Weizen zt so in
      ...
```

Or use a single `let` expression:

```
let
  zt = [Tomate, Fleisch, Fleisch]
  so = Mayo (Ketchup Keine)
  dw = Burger Weizen zt so
in ...
```

Complete example:

```
data Zutat = Tomate | Fleisch | Salat
  deriving (Show)

data Bun = Weizen | Roggen
  deriving (Show)

data Sosse = Ketchup Sosse | Mayo Sosse | Keine
  deriving (Show)

data Burger = Burger Bun [Zutat] Sosse
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = let
  zt = [Tomate, Fleisch, Fleisch]
  so = Mayo (Ketchup Keine)
  dw = Burger Weizen zt so
  in print dw
```

Output:

```
Burger Weizen [Tomate,Fleisch,Fleisch] (Mayo (Ketchup Keine))
```

It sounds like you need to consult a reference on basic Haskell syntax.